# Getting list of buddypress users into an array based on criteria

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, buddypress

I am using buddypress on a wordpress installation. I would like to get an array of `user_id`s into a variable which I can then use to manipulate, for example, list in HTML or send messages to.

I have tried using the following code. I have verified my SQL query is correct via phpmyadmin.

```
function my_bp_get_users_by_xprofile( $field_id, $value ) {

    global $wpdb;

    $user_ids = $wpdb->get_col(
        $wpdb->prepare(
            "
                SELECT `user_id`
                FROM '{$wpdb->prefix}bp_xprofile_data'
                WHERE `field_id` = %d
                    AND `value` = %s
            "
            , $field_id
            , $value
        )
    );
}
```

Then on the page, I want to do something like this:

```
$user_ids = my_bp_get_users_by_xprofile( 5, '%18%' );
echo $user_ids;
```

I have also verified the location of my php ([bp-custom](https://codex.buddypress.org/themes/bp-custom-php/)) by invoking a simple function that simply echos a string.

Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I think you're missing a return in your function, so you're calling the method but not returning anything.

```
function my_bp_get_users_by_xprofile( $field_id, $value ) {
    global $wpdb;

    $user_ids = $wpdb->get_col(
        $wpdb->prepare(
            "
                SELECT `user_id`
                FROM '{$wpdb->prefix}bp_xprofile_data'
                WHERE `field_id` = %d
                    AND `value` = %s
            "
            , $field_id
            , $value
        )
    );

    // Return only if there are user_id's found
    if (!empty($user_ids) {
        return $user_ids;
    }

    // Return false if nothing found
    return false;
}
```

Then in your template you'd need to also check if its not empty:

```
$user_ids = my_bp_get_users_by_xprofile( 5, '%18%' );
if ($user_ids) {
    // You first need to see what the structure of the returned array is and what values the indexes have
    echo $user_ids['value'];
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. It's giving me a syntax error on the line `if (!empty($user_ids) {`: unexpected `{` which then gives me a `HTTP ERROR 500` when I load the page.

Comment: Yep, you're trying to echo $user_ids which should be an array. Try echo print_r($user_ids, true); and see what structure the array is in.

Comment: I replaced the last section with just `return $user_ids;` for now as I'm struggling, and then used `echo print_r($user_ids, true);` which gives `Array ( )` - very frustrating! Maybe I should try to print the entire table to see if it is even reading anything??

Comment: If it's giving you an empty array then it means your query isn't returning anything! I've updated my original answer to give you an example on how to handle this in the template

Comment: Thank you! I tried printing a couple of columns from the table to see if it was reading and it was! So it must be the query..... thanks for your help.

Comment: Not a problem, please select this as correct answer if it helped!

Comment: In an attempt to remove wildcard searches, I've also tried this: $user_ids = my_bp_get_users_by_xprofile( 1, 'admin' );echo print_r($user_ids, true);` which should at least return `1` as that is the `user_id` of 'admin' from the `field_id` being the username. It's not working and I'm not sure where to go from here.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/155215/discussion-between-giolliano-sulit-and-redditor).